# Split text regex Java

Tags: java, regex, split

Hi I have a text file that i want to split.

> Chapter 1 : The grey warm evening of August had descended upon the city and a mild warm air, a memory of summer, circulated in the streets. The streets, shuttered for the repose of Sunday, swarmed with a gaily coloured crowd. Like illumined pearls the lamps shone from the summits of their tall poles upon the living texture below which, changing shape and hue unceasingly, sent up into the warm grey evening air an unchanging unceasing murmur.
>   Chapter 2 : Two young men came down the hill of Rutland Square. On of them was just bringing a long monologue to a close. The other, who walked on the verge of the path and was at times obliged to step on to the road, owing to his companion's rudeness, wore an amused listening face. He was squat and ruddy. A yachting cap was shoved far back from his forehead and the narrative to which he listened made constant waves of expression break forth over his face from the corners of his nose and eyes and mouth. Little jets of wheezing laughter followed one another out of his convulsed body. His eyes, twinkling with cunning enjoyment, glanced at every moment towards his companion's face. Once or twice he rearranged the light waterproof which he had slung over one shoulder in toreador fashion. His breeches, his white rubber shoes and his jauntily slung waterproof expressed youth. But his figure fell into rotundity at the waist, his hair was scant and grey and his face, when the waves of expression had passed over it, had a ravaged look.

How to split the text into 2 parts by the "Chapter" of the text?

I have use regex `Chapter 1 : .+ Chapter` but the result it delete the Chapter words.

Comment: Kindly specify the problem u r facing.

Comment: The problem is about how to split that text file, and make it into 2 text(String). So as  example the first 1 is Chapter 1 : ...................... and the other variable is chapter 2 : ...................................

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be what you're looking for if you want to use a *split* function:

```
(?!^)(?=Chapter\s\d+\s:)
```

If you're just wanting to capture the chapters, try this:

```
Chapter\s\d+\s:.*?(?=Chapter\s\d+\s:|$)
```

https://regex101.com/r/oE5rX6/1

Which can be shortened to this:

`Chapter.*?(?=Chapter|$)`

But just in case you get some false positives with the word `Chapter` appearing in the text, it might be better to be more explicit as in the previous expression.

In all of the cases, it is using a [positive lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to match what is needed.